# CSS - Amazon Associate link formatting with CSS

Tags: css

The link below was black with no underline, then black with an underline when hovered. This is what I wanted. Then I turned it into an Amazon Associate link, and now it's blue & underlined. I'm still using the same CSS as before (links2), so I don't understand why it changed format.

How can I get the link to be black with no underline, then black with underline when hovered?

The link:

```php
'<a type="amzn" category="books" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'
```

The CSS:

```css
a.links2:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a.links2:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a.links2:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a.links2:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is putting

```
!important
```

after the styling in your style sheet that sets the color to black.

as in:

```
color: #000000 !important;
```

This gives priority to your styling over the Amazon one.

Answer (score 1):

is there any css associated with "Amazon Associate link" ?

if you use firebug and hover over the links you can find all the css associated with that link and also the properties which were overridden